# Setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND remotely

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ssh, remote-login

Is there any way to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` when executing a script remotely via SSH?

Doing so I get this error:

```
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: DEBIAN_FRONTEND
```

The reason I want to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` at exactly this place is because sometimes `apt-get dist-upgrade` shows a mask for some user interaction (whiptail). As want to run this script remotely via `crontab -e` there is no human to klick or press anything. Hence, I need to turn that off as the script would otherwise remain stuck.

The script I am trying to execute is located on `server_one` in `/usr/local/bin/perform-update`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y autoremove
sudo snap refresh
```

I try to call it from `server_two` using this command:

```
SERVER_COMMAND="perform-update"
ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa backupuser@server_one $SERVER_COMMAND
```

I have also set the appropriate rights for `backupuser` on `server_one` in `sudo visudo`:

```
backupuser      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/perform-update
backupuser      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
backupuser      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/snap
```

Comment: You should secure your visudo ASAP by following muru's answer completely. I was exploring using APT options to set the environment variable, only to realize that I could run any command using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could allow the user to set the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable when using `sudo`, but ... you have granted permission for the user to execute the script using `sudo`, so there's no reason to then use `sudo` *inside* the script. Just run the script itself with `sudo`.

Change your script to:

```
#! /bin/bash
apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y dist-upgrade
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y autoremove
snap refresh
```

And then run it using:

```
ssh -i "$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa" backupuser@server_one sudo "$SERVER_COMMAND"
```

---

*That said*, you should be using `unattended-upgrades` instead of re-inventing the wheel.

---

For the particular case of allowing a user to set an environment variable for a specific command, add the `SETENV` tag in addition to the `NOPASSWD` tag. From [`man sudoers`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man5/sudoers.5.html#sudoers%20file%20format):

```
 SETENV and NOSETENV

   These tags override the value of the setenv flag on a per-command basis.  If SETENV has
   been set for a command, the user may disable the env_reset flag from the command line via
   the -E option.  Additionally, environment variables set on the command line are not
   subject to the restrictions imposed by env_check, env_delete, or env_keep.  As such, only
   trusted users should be allowed to set variables in this manner.  If the command matched
   is ALL, the SETENV tag is implied for that command; this default may be overridden by use
   of the NOSETENV tag.
```

So the rule should look like:

```
backupuser      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:SETENV: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Comment: Good point for removing `sudo` within `perform-update` and running the script already using `sudo` remotely. Also, good point to use `unattended-upgrades`. Adding `SETENV` to the line already containing `ALL` seems unnecessary as it is already included: `If the command matched
   is ALL, the SETENV tag is implied for that command`. Is there any reason you suggested to add it nevertheless?

Comment: @Socrates ah, but you're not using `ALL` for the _commands_. You have specifically listed `/usr/bin/apt-get` as the command. If you were using `ALL` for commands, the line would be `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Got it! There would be a third `ALL`. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: @muru I don't recommend encouraging putting `apt-get` in a sudoers rule for security reasons. I explained how you can break out of `apt-get` to run any command you want.

Comment: @DanielT agreed. In general I'd say there are a few commands to which, if you give unrestricted access like OP does, it's pretty much equivalent to root. `apt-get` is one even without any option shenanigans, since the ability to install any arbitrary package basically gives you root. Just build a trivial deb package and have its `preinst` do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

For all practical intents and purposes please see [@muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1501935/1004020). If in a hurry, only the `sudo` change on the `ssh` line on server_two is necessary, and the `/usr/local/bin/perform-update` script on server_one does not need to be edited. But for security reasons, it should be followed in its entirety, plus my edit at the end of my answer.

What if we consider things the other way? What if we couldn't change the command on server_two and could only change the command on server_one? I was looking for an APT option to just set an environment variable, but I found more than I expected. Here is an outrageous out-of-the-box answer just to demonstrate that your `/etc/sudoers` policy needs to be secured.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Put this in /usr/local/bin/perform-update
# No need to manually change any other file

# Use the -o to inject any arbitrary apt-config option.
# First write a wrapper file to execute later that
# sets up DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive and passes on the arguments.
sudo apt-get update -o APT::Update::Pre-Invoke::='echo '\'$'#!/bin/sh\nexport DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive\nexec /usr/bin/dpkg "$@"'\'' > /usr/dpkg; chmod 700 /usr/dpkg'
# Then use -o again to make dist-upgrade use the wrapper.
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade -o Dir::Bin::dpkg=/usr/dpkg
# autoremove should use DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive too because
# removing some packages like display managers may cause prompting.
sudo apt-get -y autoremove -o Dir::Bin::dpkg=/usr/dpkg
sudo snap refresh
```

I do not think you intended to give `backupuser` full root access. To secure your system, you need to the remove `apt-get` and `snap` lines in `visudo`, then follow @muru's answer.

EDIT: Except you need to remove `apt-get` line instead in `visudo`. Those 3 lines should be replaced with just the first line:

```
backupuser      ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/perform-update
```